# Having issue with UIPageControl and scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to fire a method when `_pageControl.currentPage` is at exact page number , but the problem is when user scrolls to another page , compiler detects new page while is still scrolling ! I need to fire my method when scrolling done ! here is my codes :

```
- (void)setupPageScroll {

    _pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    _pageControl.numberOfPages = 5;
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * _pageControl.numberOfPages, _scrollView.frame.size.width)];
    _scrollView.delegate = self;

    [self createPageWithView:_logo forPage:0];
    [self createPageWithView:_news forPage:1];

}

- (void)createPageWithView:(UIView *)iview forPage:(int)page
{


    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                       CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * page, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [newView addSubview:iview];
    [_scrollView addSubview:newView];
}




- (IBAction)pageChanged:(id)sender {
    CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(_pageControl.currentPage * _scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible: pageRect animated: YES];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) sView
{



    CGFloat offset = _scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat pageSize = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((offset + (pageSize/2)) / pageSize);
    _pageControl.currentPage = page;

    switch (_pageControl.currentPage) {

        case 0:
                   NSLog(@"1");
         break;

        case 1:
                 NSLog(@"2");
        break;



    default:

        break;

    }

}
```

here is compiler's result :

> 2014-08-27 13:48:35.344 TADAEX[45131:60b] 1 2014-08-27 13:48:35.361
>   TADAEX[45131:60b] 1 2014-08-27 13:48:35.378 TADAEX[45131:60b] 1
>   2014-08-27 13:48:37.248 TADAEX[45131:60b] 1 2014-08-27 13:48:37.265
>   TADAEX[45131:60b] 1 2014-08-27 13:48:37.282 TADAEX[45131:60b] 1
>   2014-08-27 13:48:37.299 TADAEX[45131:60b] 2 2014-08-27 13:48:38.076
>   TADAEX[45131:60b] 2 2014-08-27 13:48:38.076 TADAEX[45131:60b] 2
>   2014-08-27 13:48:38.076 TADAEX[45131:60b] 2 2014-08-27 13:48:38.076
>   TADAEX[45131:60b] 2 2014-08-27 13:48:38.076 TADAEX[45131:60b] 2

as you see compiler repeats giving `NSLog` output ! not when pageControl is at the exact page number .

Comment: Yes, that's normal. scrollViewDidScroll fires while the user is scrolling.

Comment: better option is use if - else instead of Switch case. you can do like this if(page == 1) ->  NSLog(@"1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in this delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
//Tells the delegate that the scroll view has ended decelerating the scrolling movement.
}
```